# It is possible to solve equation R that are not linear?

Tags: r, data-analysis, normal-distribution

I want to build a function that takes E[x] and  Var[X] and give me the mean and standard error of a univariate lognormal variable.

```
E[x] = exp(mu + theta) 
Var[x] =  exp(2*mu + theta)*(exp(theta) - 1)
```

The function would take `E[x]` and `Var[x]` as input and as output would give me `theta` and `mu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several packages that provide ways and means to solve a system of nonlinear equations. One of these is `nleqslv`.

You nee to provide a function that function that returns the differences between the actual value of the equations and the desired value.

Load package `nleqslv` and define the following function

```
library(nleqslv)

f <- function(x,Ex,Varx) {
    y<- numeric(length(x))    
    mu <- x[1]
    theta <- x[2]
    y[1] <- exp(mu+theta) - Ex
    y[2] <- exp(2*mu+theta)*(exp(theta)-1) - Varx

    y
}
```

The vector `x` in the function contains the values of `mu` and `theta`.
An example with `Ex=2` and `Varx=3` and some random starting values

```
xstart <- c(1,1)
nleqslv(xstart,f,Ex=2,Varx=3)
```

gives the following

```
$x
[1] -0.6931472  1.3862944

$fvec
[1] -8.095125e-11 -8.111645e-11

$termcd
[1] 1

$message
[1] "Function criterion near zero"

$scalex
[1] 1 1

$nfcnt
[1] 31

$njcnt
[1] 2

$iter
[1] 22
```

See the manual of `nleqslv` for the meaning of the different elements of the return value of `nleqslv`.

If you want to investigate the effect of the different solving methods try this

```
testnslv(xstart,f,Ex=2,Varx=3)
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect answer, but I used the "BB" package that I found to be better, but your answer is perfect either way